# How can I test working of amp-form in a localhost

Tags: amp-html

How can I test working of amp-form in localhost, I heard that form action must be an https url, Is there any way to test it locally

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in server that comes with checking out the AMP HTML code. Please check out the getting [started guide](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/contributing/getting-started-quick.md). Once you checkout the code you can simply run 'gulp --extensions=amp-form' or just 'gulp' to bring up the local server. Then in you browser point to localhost:8080/examples/forms.amp.html. This is a sample forms page that you can use to test amp-form. If you need to test out a particular expected response or data, just modify the code in the [following](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/d74d3f445b647dbec5e0599a53b954f4d92128c1/build-system/app.js).